# Google Chrome using incorrect resolution on external monitor

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, resolution, ubuntu-14.04

I recently bought a new laptop. Its a Dell XPS 13 Developer edition (Which means it uses Ubuntu 14.04 rather than widows 10)

I've only really run into one snafu which has to do with Google Chrome.

The built in display is 1920x1080 and the two external monitors are (though bigger) 1600x900.

Everything looks fine on them except google chrome. When I connect to the external monitors, everything looks much larger than it should. Also, for some reason, when I right-click, the context-menu shows up on the built in display, no matter which monitor the browser window is sitting in.

If I drag the window over to the built in display, everything looks fine again.

This only happens with google chrome. Neither Chromium or Firefox have this issue.

I have tried reinstalling chrome with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You have resolution and DPI. DPI means dots per inch and is roughly the amount of pixels per 2.5cm. If your dpi is high everything will appear smaller regardless of resolution. I do not know how to set dpi for each screen separatly but this should guide you to what you are looking for.